# What does it mean when device needs a voltage drop to function?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, circuit-design

Sorry if this is a badly worded question, still learning electronics and don't know specifically what to ask yet.

I'm new to electronics and working on a problem that requires me to find resistor values so that a fan will work with a voltage drop of 5V. I've attached a picture of the circuit as well.

I'm not sure quite what it exactly means by a voltage drop. To me the only logical answer is that when the voltage passes through the fan the voltage would just drop by 5V. But I'm struggling to understand this concept and how it can be used to help design and analyze circuit diagrams. Is it the resistor that makes the voltage drop or the fan itself? This idea has confused me and tends to get me stuck on a lot of problems like this.

Thank you

This is the full context of the question:
[image]

Then the sub part asks to find the values of the resistors R1 and R2 so that the fan works with a 5V voltage drop.

Edit:
I don't have a characteristic curve of the fan but I have one of the transistor. Shown below

[image]

Circuit diagram

[image]

Edit 2: My bad the curve was on a different page, thank you all for being patient

[image]

Comment: "so that a fan will work with a voltage drop of 5 V" is not a sentence that means much of anything to experienced electrical engineers (well, at least to me, one specific experienced EE) either. Is there any clarifying information? What is the entirety of the problem statement you're trying to solve?

Comment: Can you show the characteristic curve for the fan.  I suspect that that is required to answer the question.  I think they mean that the fan is designed to operate on 5 volts, but without seeing the characteristic curve, that's only a guess.

Comment: A picture of the fan label would help us guide you in your quest.

Comment: It does not help at all if others need to guess at the parameters of the fan. To answer the question efficiently more information for the fan is required. The quoted question claims that the characteristic curve for the fan was supplied.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

voltage drop = potential difference

Your fan needs at least 5V between the red terminal and the black terminal to operate.

A typical PC case fan could be damaged by 24V (most are designed to operate from 12V). This is the reason for the resistor in series with the fan.

Answer (score 1):

I see the updated characteristic curve for the fan. Glad you added that.

Although this looks very much like homework to me, I also doubt my answer will make a lot of sense:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fnmudt.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

You are allowed only one 2N2222 but an *assortment* of resistors. Hopefully, that assortment comes in varying dissipations. The above circuit will keep the BJT's dissipation low enough that it won't need any special handling. It will also draw well below (perhaps as low as 20% but almost certainly will not exceed 40%) the limit of \$5\:\text{mA}\$ from the Arduino I/O pin. It includes provision in case the I/O pin isn't yet hooked up to the circuit (either during power-up or just because the wire isn't connected.) And another detail or two that help a little.

The above is set up as a voltage-controlled current sink.

Answer (score 0):

The problem statement you provided worded it badly. It says you are using a separate 24V supply, so in that case your fan needs to be 24V. They might be saying that the 24V fan will just begin to run (very slowly) at 5V, but this depends on the fan and in any case this circuit cannot effectively control the fan's voltage.

The resistor in series is a very shoddy way of reducing the voltage to the fan and given the difference of fan nameplate currents to actual running currents (usually less than nameplate), you stand a high risk of overvolting and burning out your fan.  Furthermore, dropping 5V over the resistor would still be supplying 19V to either a 12V or 5V computer fan so I'm not sure if that was even the author's intention at all.

If you are not married to the 24V supply (and from the information you've given, there's really no reason you should be, in fact I don't think I've ever seen a 24V computer case fan), you can use either a 12V fan and a 12V power supply or a 5V fan and a 5V power supply. The fan could introduce some noise into the power rail; whether this will affect the Arduino depends on the fan and the power supply and cannot be definitively answered without trying it first but it might be easiest to use a single 12V power supply to power the fan and the Arduino together and let the filtering of the Arduino's onboard regulator get rid of any conducted grossness from the fan. However, this is probably not a great choice if you are going to be powering additional things off of the Arduino's 5V or 3.3V rails since the onboard linear regulator can't handle a whole lot of current at 12V input.

Also note that the ground of the Arduino and the ground of the transistor need to be connected together to work, even if the Arduino and fan are being supplied by separate power supplies.